# How do I create PsiSwitchLabelStatement in idea plugin Development?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

The source code：

```
swich(i){
case 1:
break;
case 2:
break;
}
```

I want to insert "case", but how do I create PsiSwitchLabelStatement?

Answer (score 1):

You can create any Java statement using this method:

```
PsiElementFactory.SERVICE.getInstance(project).createStatementFromText(text, null)
```

Comment: That's just what I was thinking.but i use this to create whitespace or '\r\n' i always give error

Comment: it throw a error : "IncorrectOperationException: Incorrect statement 'case 1:break;'"

Comment: There are other ways to do ?@yole